# PHP: Add attachments to emails "on the fly"?

Tags: php, email, file, attachment

I just got PHP's mail function to work properly in my test environment.

I have a PHP app that outputs a number of strings. It would be really nice to convert these strings to attachments (`*.TXT` -files) in an email, without first storing them on disk and having to read them back. **Would this be possible in PHP?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to make your email message a [multipart message](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-5.1) with the following syntax:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=random-boundary

This is the optional preamble of a multipart/mixed message.
--random-boundary
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the main message body.
--random-boundary
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.txt

This is the content of the attached file.
--random-boundary--
This is the optional epilogue of a multipart/mixed message.
```

Each part can then be described like any other message. But you should probably use a library that does this for you.

Now if you’re using [PHP’s `mail` function](http://php.net/mail), the first two line would be the header and the rest would be the contents of that mail message. The boundary should be a random boundary so that the possibility of having that string with `--` in front of it being in the contents of one part is very unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Took some time to get it running but it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use e.g. [PEAR's Mail_Mine](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/redirected) class for it.

[`bool addAttachment ( string $file , string $c_type = 'application/octet-stream' , string $name = '' , boolean $isfile = true , string $encoding = 'base64' )`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.addattachment.php) is the method you want to use, with `$file` containing your strings and `$isfile` being `false`.

Answer (score 1):

And you can Use Zend_Mail Classes for much easier code 
the file name would be `"smapleFilename"` and its the last parameter in `createAttachment` function 
but don't foget to setup your `transport` before that 
sample :

```
    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
        $mail->setBodyText("body")
             ->createAttachment("your wanted text " ,  Zend_Mime::TYPE_TEXT,               
                                 Zend_Mime::DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT , Zend_Mime::ENCODING_BASE64, "smapleFilename.txt");
        $mail->setFrom('test@222222.com', 'Server');
        $mail->addTo('test@hotmail.com');
        $mail->setSubject("subject");
        $mail->send();
```

in Zend framework project you would do like this :

```
resources.mail.transport.type = smtp
resources.mail.transport.host = "mail.111111.com"
resources.mail.transport.auth = login
resources.mail.transport.username = test@111111.com
resources.mail.transport.password = test
;resources.mail.transport.ssl = tls
resources.mail.transport.port = 2525
resources.mail.transport.register = true ; True by default
```