# ASIHTTPRequest + PHP Form

Tags: php, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am sending some information to a php script of mine which in return sends an e-mail.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
$to = $_POST['to'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = $_POST ['from'];
$headers = "From: Test";
if (mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
{
echo "Message sent.";
}
else
{
echo "Failed to send message.";
}
?>
```

My implementation works fine, the e-mail gets sent with the data I want to be sent - but I want to attach an image as well. My PHP knowledge is near zero, so I was wondering if someone could be so kind an help me out with my script?

Here's my iPhone implementation of ASIHTTPRequest:

```
datarequest = [[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/email.php"]];

[datarequest setPostValue:to forKey:@"to"];

if (self.message != nil)
{
[datarequest setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",self.message,description.text] forKey:@"message"];
}

else
{
[datarequest setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",description.text] forKey:@"message"];
}

[datarequest setPostValue:subject forKey:@"subject"];
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([images lastObject]);
[datarequest addData:imageData forKey:@"image"];//here's the image that I want to add to the email
```

Comment: You want the image in the body of the email or as an attachment ?

Comment: I want it in the body of the email..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching a file using `mail()` is possible, but requires rather complicated fiddling with multipart messages.

The usual recommendation is to use an advanced PHP mailer like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Attaching files is shown [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-attachments).

Comment: thanks - but as I've said my php knowledge is bad, i'm an iPhone/Mac developer only and that's the only time that i've had to use php to get a task done :P

Comment: @David here are two examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279577/php-add-attachments-to-emails-on-the-fly