# Attach excel stream to swiftmailer message?

Tags: php, excel, symfony, swiftmailer

I'm trying to attach an Excel file in a SwiftMailer message.

The trick is that I don't want to save the excel file and then attach it and then delete it, instead I just want to generate the excel and attach that to the message.

This function allows to attach a OutputByteStream

```
/**
 * Create a new Attachment.
 *
 * @param string|Swift_OutputByteStream $data
 * @param string                        $filename
 * @param string                        $contentType
 *
 * @return Swift_Mime_Attachment
 */
public static function newInstance($data = null, $filename = null, $contentType = null)
{
    return new self($data, $filename, $contentType);
}
```

There is a function in Symfony PHPExcel bundle to create the response

```
/**
 * Stream the file as Response.
 *
 * @param \PHPExcel_Writer_IWriter $writer
 * @param int                      $status
 * @param array                    $headers
 *
 * @return StreamedResponse
 */
public function createStreamedResponse(\PHPExcel_Writer_IWriter $writer, $status = 200, $headers = array())
{
    return new StreamedResponse(
        function () use ($writer) {
            $writer->save('php://output');
        },
        $status,
        $headers
    );
}
```

They seems to call to that callback when they are rendering the reponse, but How can I save the php://output in a variable or something to pass it to newInstance method?

I tried passing the response object (StreamedResponse) but it only have the headers, I also tried with $response->getContent() and passing $writer->save('php://output') to newInstance method.

Comment: Would this be useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279577/php-add-attachments-to-emails-on-the-fly

Comment: I saved php://output with ob_start() and ob_get_clean()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use stream_get_contents

```
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance(stream_get_contents(createStreamedResponse(...)), 'test.xls', 'application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

(dont know hat your actual mimetype is)

Answer (score 2):

I made the trick like this :

Firstly, I use the output buffering and retrieve the content of the output buffer :

```
    ob_start();
    $writer = new Xlsx($excelFile);
    $writer->save('php://output');
    $data = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

Then I retrieve the $attachement :

```
$attachment = \Swift_Attachment::newInstance($data, $fileName, 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
```

Finally I attach the file to the mail like in the SwiftMailer documentation :

```
$email->attach($attachment);
```

Answer (score 1):

With the new Symfony Mailer component you can do that :

```
//same as @tCot response
ob_start();
$writer = new Xlsx($excelFile);
$writer->save('php://output');
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

And in your email declaration :

```
$email->embed($data, $filename) //The third parameters (mime type) can be guess by Symfony
```